# No privileges on xampp server phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, privileges

[image]

As you can see, there is no privileges tab, and I can't a create new database

Comment: Are you logged as root?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is because you're not actually logged in as the user you think you are, but as the anonymous user instead. Double check your username and password, and make sure the host field is matching for the account you're trying to log in to. For example, if you're able to connect through the command line client which connects over sockets, your host is 'localhost' but if phpMyAdmin is using the TCP connection type, your host will be 127.0.0.1 instead; these aren't the same to the MySQL permissions system. If you changed the root password for root@localhost but not root@127.0.0.1 it won't match the new password in this case.